# Howto route traffic to GKE private master from another VPC network

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Can I route requests to GKE private master from another VPC? I can’t seem to find any way to setup GCP router to achieve that:

- balancers can't use master ip as a backend in any way
- routers can't have next-hop-ip from another network
- I can't (on my own) peer different VPC network with master private network
- when I peer GKE VPC with another VPC, those routes are not propagated

Any solution here?

PS: Besides creating a standalone proxy or using third-party router...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Kubernetes normally assumes all nodes can talk to each other - what you describe would break that? Can you maybe solve your problem by having 2 independent GKE clusters and then use Istio to expose services accross both?

Comment: @mensi I have multiple gcp projects, kube clusters are in separate project. I want my CI (which is in different project) to be able to access private kube master.

Comment: You should avoid tight coupling like that - it would be better if CI pushes the artifacts to something like GCR and you use a different process (eg PubSub, periodic scheduled rollouts, ...) to update your deployements rather than directly manipulating the master.

Comment: @mensi this makes no sense for me: 1. gcp is not the only platform we use for deployment. 2. We want interaction with master to be available for admins. 3. You have to make initial setup (like autodeployment setup) in the first place - this all requires some external access to the cluster api.

Comment: @user2672943 have you found a solution or a workaround yet? I have the same problem, and I am not able to solve it :/ The only way seems to have a public master, but that's what I don't want to do...

Comment: @ThomasBöhm no, the only way is custom router with SNAT or web proxy to proxy requests to master (which is the same solution on different levels of TCP/IP stack).

Answer (score 2):

> I have multiple gcp projects, kube clusters are in separate project.

This dramatically changes the context of your question as VPC from other projects aren't routeable by simply adding project-level network rules.

For cross-project VPC peering, you need to set up a [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

> I want my CI (which is in different project) to be able to access private kube master.

For this, each GKE private cluster has [Master Authorized Networks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#overview), which are basically IP addresses/CIDRs that are allowed to authenticate with the master endpoint for administration.

If your CI has a unified address or if the administrators have fixed IPs, you can add them to these networks so that they can authenticate to the master.

If there are not unified addresses for these clients, then depending on your specific scenario, you might need some sort of SNATing to "*unify*" the source of your requests to match the authorized addresses.

Additionally, you can make a private cluster without a public address. This will allow access to the master endpoint to the nodes allocated in the cluster VPC. However:

> There is still an external IP address used by Google for cluster management purposes, but the IP address is not accessible to anyone.

Comment: Deleted previous comment to clarify that now GKE offers also internal IPs for the masters, [available only for the VPC where the nodes are hosted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters). You need to disable "Access master using its external IP address". I think this one suits your needs.

Comment: No, it does not: I'm very well aware, that GKE offers private access to masters. My question is - how do I access master via internal IP form different VPC (not the one kube cluster is located in).

Comment: It's stated that "for cross-project VPC peering, you need to set up a VPC Network Peering". Once your two VPCs can see each other, you should be able to hit the private master endpoint. If this is not adequate, elaborate on the question's restriction: whether they're technical or business restraints.

Comment: > Once your two VPCs can see each other, you should be able to hit the private master endpoint.

This is incorrect: master endpoint is located in separate VPC (in completely different, Google-managed project). To access private master IP this VPC should have routing to my VPC. Google peering does not import custom routes, so routes from non-kuber VPC are missing from this project.

Comment: @user2672943 did you ever figure this out?

Comment: > did you ever figure this out?
@SpaceMan well, sort of...

In short - you can't do that without custom router or proxy. The problem is - the scheme described requires SNAT to work (because google peering does not import custom routes).

Answer (score 1):

not supported by google, workarounds exists (but they are dirty):
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244483997  , custom routes export/import has no effect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Google finally added custom routes export to VPC peering with master subnet. So the problem is now gone, you can access private master from different VPC or through VPN.

Comment: can you update answer more to describe your solution in a bit more detailed? I have similar case where I want to access the GKE private ip from different project/vpc.

Comment: This is not entirely true, private clusters are VPC peered with your project's VPC, and the custom routes are indeed exported to your VPC, but since VPCs are not transitive with regards to routes, any other VPC you peer to the first one will not be able to reach the master node or the K8s API. A proxy does work, for example an NGINX ingress declared to route everything to kubernetes in the default namespace, that plus a cert-manager allows you to securely connect to the K8s API from another VPC by using an internal LB.